# PHP Function Arguments: Array of Objects of a Specific Class

Tags: php, arrays, function, object, arguments

I have a function that takes a member of a particular class:

```
public function addPage(My_Page $page)
{
  // ...
}
```

I'd like to make another function that takes an array of My_Page objects:

```
public function addPages($pages)
{
  // ...
}
```

I need to ensure that each element of $pages array is an instance of My_Page. I could do that with `foreach($pages as $page)` and check for `instance of`, but can I somehow specify in the function definition that the array has to be an array of My_Page objects? Improvising, something like:

```
public function addPages(array(My_Page)) // I realize this is improper PHP...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do directly. You might try this "clever" trick instead:

```
public function addPages(array $pages)
{
    foreach($pages as $page) addPage($page);
}

public function addPage(My_Page $page)
{
    //
}
```

But I 'm not sure if it's worth all the trouble. It would be a good approach if `addPage` is useful on its own.

Answer (score 17):

You can also add PhpDoc comment to get autocomplete in IDE

```
    /**
     * @param My_Page[] $pages
     */
    public function addPages(array $pages)
    {
      // ...
    }
```

Comment: This is helping and with VS code and the https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense it's very helpful with the autocomplete :)

Answer (score 4):

From php5.6 you can use **splat operator** to type hint all array elements as function params. In this case you don't have more parameters than Pages stored in array so it should work fine:

```
public function addPages(Page ...$pages)
```

More info:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php

https://lornajane.net/posts/2014/php-5-6-and-the-splat-operator

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing an array of objects (`array(My_Page)`), define your own class and require an instance of it in your function:

```
class MyPages { ... }

public function addPages(MyPages pages)
```

Comment: and how exactly I'm able to store an indefinite amount of specific objects in that class?

Comment: @goose I have no idea what I meant with this answer back then, sorry. This answer looks pretty useless to me

Comment: xd it's kk. but it's weird that 2 dudes upvoted it and found this useful

Answer (score 0):

if you use the class, you can do some thing like this:

```
interface addPageInterface
{
   public function someThing();
}


class page implements addPageInterface
{
   public function someThing()
   {
      //for example: create a page
   }
}


class addPage
{
   public function __construct(addPageInterface $page)
   {
       //do some thing...

      return $page; //this will return just one page
   }
}


class addPages
{
   public function __construct(addPageInterface... $page)
   {
      //do some thing...

      return $page; //this will return an array which contains of page
   }
}
```

Comment: Give proper explanation with your answer with proper reasoning.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
        
    class Page{
            public $a;
    }
        
    
    function addPages(Page ...$pages){
        foreach($pages as $page){
        
        }
    }
        
        
    $pages = [];
    $pages[]  = new Page;
    $pages[]  = new Page;
    $pages[]  = new Page;
    addPages(...$pages);
    
?>
```

i think its better way

Comment: Explain why do you think this is a better way please.

Comment: This will throw an error: Argument #1 must be type of Page, array given.

Comment: Its not throwing any error after version 7.0 its working successfuly