# PHP declaring object as array for function parameter

Tags: php, arrays

I'm quite new with PHP. I'm having problems declaring an object as array for function parameter. In Java, I simply use `public void methodName (List<Object> listVariableName){}` for passing a list of many Objects.

I did some research in PHP and one of the answers suggested to put `array` in method parameter declaration like so `function myFunction($a, array Object $obj){}`

Currently, I have a class named `Lesson`

```
class Lesson implements JsonSerializable{
private $lessonId;
    private $lessonNo;
    private $lessonTitle;
    private $isLessonActive;
    private $isLessonRemoved;

    //getters and setter here....
}
```

Then I'm trying to declare a method called `addTopicLesson`

```
function addTopicLesson(Topic $topic, array Lesson $lesson){

}
```

But, I'm getting an error in `array Lesson $lesson`

There's 1 topic and MANY lessons. How can I go about implementing or defining the method signature?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523062/php-function-arguments-array-of-objects-of-a-specific-class) but I'd like to know if there's a better approach than to call itself.

I'd appreciate any suggestion.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't type hint `array of Objects`, either `array` or `Object`

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>` is not an array.  It's a list utilizing generic type mechanism.

There are no generics in  PHP. You can only typehint an `array` but you cannot control what's inside it at the level of method declaration.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addTopicLesson(Topic $topic,array $lessons)
{
  foreach($lessons as $lesson) 
  {
    addLesson($page);
  }
}

function addLesson(Lesson $lesson)
{
}
```

Comment: This way you can pass only one instance of `Lesson` object. It will refuse to take an array.