# How can I pass an array of object to a function?

Tags: php, model

I would like to use `public function __construct(Condition[] $conditions, Action $action)` in the function below.

But `PHP` don't able to use `Condition[]` as a parameter.

Using this approach I could pass `[1, 2, 3]` to this model.

Is there some workaround to solve this?

```
/**
 * Rule constructor.
 *
 * @param Condition[] $conditions
 * @param Action $action
 */
public function __construct(array $conditions, Action $action)
{
    $this->conditions = $conditions;
    $this->action = $action;
}
```

`PHP Version: 7.2.x`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Function Arguments: Array of Objects of a Specific Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523062/php-function-arguments-array-of-objects-of-a-specific-class)

Comment: Thanks Tiago, It isn't exactly what I am looking for. But... Helps indeed.